# Selecting rows from csv for a particular day in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, csv

I have a CSV file called `test.csv` containing these values :

```
A,table,20191229 16:41:58  
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58  
C,table3,20191223 16:40:58  
D,table4,20191228 16:41:58  
E,table5,20191227 16:41:58  
F,table6,20191226 16:40:58
```

I want to select only those rows where day is sunday, the date is in `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: how do you know (just by reading your file), which line is a sunday?

Comment: you have to convert the third column entry to date and then to day

Comment: you can parse your file with `cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d',' -f2` which would let you only date result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man date`, and do something like:

```
while read line ; do 
    echo "line=$line">&2
    din=$(echo "$line" | cut -d, -f3 | cut "-d " -f1)
    echo "din=$din">&2
    dayofweek=$(date --date=$din +%a)
    echo "dow=$dayofweek">&2
    if [[ "$dayofweek" = "Sun" ]] ; then  
      echo "$line"
    fi
done <test.csv 2>/dev/null
```

Remove the final `2>/dev/null` to see the debugging output.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
$ cat test.csv
A,table,20191229 16:41:58
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58
C,table3,20191223 16:40:58
D,table4,20191228 16:41:58
E,table5,20191227 16:41:58
F,table6,20191226 16:40:58
```

then using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)

```
$ mlr --csvlite --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output filter '
    strftime(strptime($3,"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"), "%w") == "0"
  ' test.csv
A,table,20191229 16:41:58
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner can give the expected result plus the possibility to extend it by pipe usage:

```
$ cat test.csv | (while read line; do day=$(date -d "$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)" +%a); echo "$line,$day"; done;) | grep ',Sun$' | cut -d, -f1-3
A,table,20191229 16:41:58
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58
```

The main logic 
`(while read line; do day=$(date -d "$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)" +%a); echo "$line,$day"; done;)`
is similar to [waltinator's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201067/527764), but, instead of filtering inside the loop, I concatenate the day of the week and allow further processing:

```
$ cat test.csv | (while read line; do day=$(date -d "$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)" +%a); echo "$line,$day"; done;) 
A,table,20191229 16:41:58,Sun
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58,Sun
C,table3,20191223 16:40:58,Mon
D,table4,20191228 16:41:58,Sat
E,table5,20191227 16:41:58,Fri
F,table6,20191226 16:40:58,Thu
```

Now, you can use `grep` for filtering `grep ',Sun$'` , including different days `grep -E ',(Sun|Sat)$'` if wanted:

```
$ cat test.csv | (while read line; do day=$(date -d "$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)" +%a); echo "$line,$day"; done;) | grep -E ',(Sun|Sat)$'
A,table,20191229 16:41:58,Sun
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58,Sun
D,table4,20191228 16:41:58,Sat
```

Finally,

And then select only the 3 original fields `cut -d, -f1-3` (here you have also freedom of change):

```
$ cat test.csv | (while read line; do day=$(date -d "$(echo $line|cut -d, -f3)" +%a); echo "$line,$day"; done;) | grep -E ',(Sun|Sat)$' | cut -d, -f1-3
A,table,20191229 16:41:58
B,table2,20191222 16:41:58
D,table4,20191228 16:41:58
```

Answer (score 0):

Matching multiple weekdays using  Sakamoto's method.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#    64 32 16  8  4  2  1
#     1  0  0  0  0  0  1 = 65 (Sat, Sun)
# Sat ´  |  |  |  |  |  |
# Fri ---´  |  |  |  |  |
# Thu ------´  |  |  |  |
# Wed ---------´  |  |  |
# Tue ------------´  |  |
# Mon ---------------´  |
# Sun ------------------´

a=(0 3 2 5 0 3 5 1 4 6 2 4)

IFS=$'\n'
for b in $(<test.csv); do
  ((c=10#${b:(-17):4})) # year
  ((d=10#${b:(-13):2})) # month
  ((e=10#${b:(-11):2})) # day
  (((1 << ((((c -= ((d < 3)))) + c / 4 - c / 100 + c / 400 + ${a[((d - 1))]} + e) % 7)) & 65)) && printf %s\\n "$b"
done
```

References:

- [Determination of the day of the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week)
- [Correctness of Sakamoto's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385190/correctness-of-sakamotos-algorithm-to-find-the-day-of-week/6385934#6385934)

Comment: `miller` is still almost 1/2 second faster on 50k lines